# How to send large files using python-flask in asynchronous mode?

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask

I'm very new to back end development. I want to upload long audio files (files that can be more than 10 or 30 mins.) to my server for some audio processing, but I'm facing http time out issues. How can I solve it? I'm using flask framework. I have to use asynchronous mode. But I'm really having trouble implementing it. (my default http time out is 300s, which is not good!)

Comment: You should try to show what code you have used or at least some more info on the server, if not it is a bit hard to propose a solution

Comment: @Mixone I have my program hosted in aws. The program takes some time for processing long audio files, when the client side goes into time out issue. How can I asynchronously run the processing in the back end and return the result? Currently the system works fine for short audio files and return the result in json format. Also, if I run in asynchronous mode, what would be the best way to return the result?

Comment: I meant that you should edit your question to give more information, I don't know enough to help you, I am just trying to make it easy for anyone else reading the question so they can help you better ^